# How to iterate over the rows of a single column of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array made up of two columns and 8269 rows. I want to be able to multiply all of the values of the second column by 10^-10. I'm new to programming and I'm not sure how to refer to every row of a single column of a NumPy array. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Comment: Use slicing: `your_array[:, 1]` refers to the second column. You can change that inplace `your_array[:, 1] *= 1e-10`.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy.nditer from @karma4917's answer:

```
import numpy as np

with np.nditer(your_array[:,1], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        x *= 10**(-10)
```

for me, it took 0.0045 seconds for an array with 2696 lines.